# iOS App Submission Rejection

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

When i submit my iOS app i got following rejection issues from apple.

**On launch and content download, your app stores 13.14MB on the user's iCloud, which does not comply with the iOS Data Storage Guidelines.**

**Next Steps**

Please verify that only the content that the user creates using your app, e.g., documents, new files, edits, etc. is backed up by iCloud as required by the iOS Data Storage Guidelines. Also, check that any temporary files used by your app are only stored in the /tmp directory; please remember to remove or delete the files stored in this location when it is determined they are no longer needed.
Data that can be recreated but must persist for proper functioning of your app - or because users expect it to be available for offline use - should be marked with the "do not back up" attribute. For NSURL objects, add the NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute to prevent the corresponding file from being backed up. For CFURLRef objects, use the corresponding kCRUFLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute.

Comment: So what do you want??? Clarify your problem.

Comment: how to i slove this problem

Comment: You should read about app thinning.That will give you an idea.

Comment: problem is that i saving image on camera roll may be thats why these problem is coming

Comment: We need more information... what does your app do? When are you using iCloud and what for? You can't just copy/paste a rejection message and expect people to know how it relates to your app specifically.

Comment: I create a image and i save it in camera roll using UIActivityViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Your App stores data in the users iCloud. This is only alowed to a certain degree. 
The 13,14 MB your app stores to the cloud is just too much. 
I never submitted an app to Apple, but the error message is clear and defined.

Take a look on your app and what it does store in the iCloud. Reduce the size or just dont write to iCloud.

Hope it helps...

*edit

Why would one write to the iCloud anyways? Just write on the phone memory.

Comment: I write image on camera roll.

Comment: Ok, but does the camera roll always sync with the iCloud? I dont think so.

Comment: i simply  save image into camera roll.

Answer (score 0):

Do you call a web service on App launch which stores data in the App's *documents directory*? Or do you store some other data in the App's *documents directory*?

By default all the data in the App's *documents directory* is synced to iCloud. So any data that can be recreated later (unlike session data) must not be stored on the documents directory.

So instead save data in the App's *Temp directory*.
To do that have a look at this- [How to save images and recoded files in temp directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881938/how-to-save-images-and-recoded-files-in-temp-directory)

Another option is you have is [How to use addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498752/how-to-use-addskipbackupattributetoitematurl-api)

Comment: I only save image in camera roll.

Comment: You can check the size of the data your app is saving to iCloud by going to device settings-> iCloud

Comment: Alternatively, you can programmatically, get the size http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239424/how-to-get-file-size-of-file-from-iphone-documents-folder

Comment: There is no matter of size. I only save image in camera role using uiactivityviewcontroller and image size is appx 200 kb . Don't know why getting the rejection from apple.